# Unable to automate Jmeter load testing in Bamboo

Tags: performance, testing, continuous-integration, bamboo

```html
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Build Global Digital - Application - App_Performance_Test - feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature - JMeter #3 (GDA-AP10-JOB1-3) started building on agent Elastic Agent on i-0375978d6d2732720
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Elastic agent on instance i-0375978d6d2732720
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Build working directory is /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Executing build Global Digital - Application - App_Performance_Test - feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature - JMeter #3 (GDA-AP10-JOB1-3)
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Starting task 'Checkout jmeter scripts' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.vcs:task.vcs.checkout'
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Checking out into /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Updating source code to revision: 06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Fetching 'refs/heads/feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature' from 'ssh://git@stash-QA.gd.com:7999/project/jmeter-scripts.git'. Will try to do a shallow fetch.
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:18 Warning: Permanently added '[127.0.0.1]:36663' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Checking out revision 06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6.
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Already on 'feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature'
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Updated source code to revision: 06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Finished task 'Checkout jmeter scripts' with result: Success
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Running pre-build action: VCS Version Collector
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Running pre-build action: Sauce OnDemand Build Configurator
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Running pre-build action: Hung Build Killer PreBuildAction
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Skipping execution of task 'Run jmeter scripts' as it is disabled
command 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Substituting variable: ${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.JMeter 3} with /opt/apache-jmeter-3/bin/jmeter
command 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Substituting variable: ${bamboo.build.working.directory} with /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1
simple 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Starting task 'Test script' of type 'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.scripttask:task.builder.script'
command 14-Jan-2019 15:42:19 Beginning to execute external process for build 'Global - Application - App_Performance_Test - feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature - JMeter #3 (GDA-AP10-JOB1-3)'\n ... running command line: \n/bin/sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3-ScriptBuildTask-5020464262256623767.sh\n ... in: /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1\n ... using extra environment variables: \nbamboo_planRepository_1_branch=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_duration=5\nbamboo_repository_247496707_revision_number=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_planRepository_1_branchDisplayName=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_repository_revision_number=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_repository_247496707_name=Global - jmeter-scripts\nbamboo_repository_247496707_git_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash-QA.gd.com:7999/project/jmeter-scripts.git\nbamboo_buildKey=GDA-AP10-JOB1\nbamboo_capability_remote=true\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Python_2_7=/usr/bin/python\nbamboo_shortJobName=JMeter\nbamboo_buildResultsUrl=https://bamboo-staging.qa.com/browse/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3\nbamboo_repository_247496707_git_branch=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_planRepository_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash-QA.gd.com:7999/project/jmeter-scripts.git\nbamboo_agentId=247824395\nbamboo_location=publish\nbamboo_ramp_time=1\nbamboo_planRepository_revision=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_planRepository_previousRevision=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_repository_branch_name=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_repository_247496707_branch_name=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_ci_password=********\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_Python_3=/usr/bin/python3\nbamboo_password=********\nbamboo_capability_ci=true\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_foodcritic=/opt/chefdk/bin/foodcritic\nbamboo_dependenciesDisabled=false\nbamboo_locale=en_us\nbamboo_threads=1\nbamboo_planRepository_branch=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_planRepository_1_type=bbserver\nbamboo_planRepository_branchName=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_environment=lt-000\nbamboo_gdminorversion=6313\nbamboo_capability_release=true\nbamboo_planRepository_1_username=\nbamboo_planRepository_type=bbserver\nbamboo_ManualBuildTriggerReason_userName=bv49406\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_rubocop=/opt/chefdk/bin/rubocop\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_node_Node_js=/opt/node/bin/node\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_ant_Ant=/opt/ant\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn3_Maven_3=/opt/maven/current\nbamboo_planKey=GDA-AP10\nbamboo_planRepository_username=\nbamboo_planRepository_1_branchName=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_capability_system_agent_environment_ec2_instance_type=c3.xlarge\nbamboo_resultsUrl=https://bamboo-staging.qa.com/browse/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3\nbamboo_capability_system_agent_environment_ebs_optimised=false\nbamboo_build_working_directory=/media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1\nbamboo_planRepository_1_name=Global - jmeter-scripts\nbamboo_shortPlanName=feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_ansible=/usr/local/bin/ansible\nbamboo_hybris_version=6.3.0.8\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_packer=/usr/local/bin/packer\nbamboo_planRepository_name=Global - jmeter-scripts\nbamboo_gdmajorversion=1\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_terraform=/usr/local/bin/terraform\nbamboo_buildNumber=3\nbamboo_username=admin\nbamboo_planName=Global - Application - App_Performance_Test - feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_git=/usr/bin/git\nbamboo_shortPlanKey=AP10\nbamboo_shortJobKey=JOB1\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_node_npm=/opt/node-7/bin/npm\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_JMeter_3=/opt/apache-jmeter-3/bin/jmeter\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_berkshelf=/opt/chefdk/bin/berks\nbamboo_buildTimeStamp=2019-01-14T15:42:18.663Z\nbamboo_repository_previous_revision_number=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_repository_git_branch=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_buildResultKey=GDA-AP10-JOB1-3\nbamboo_buildPlanName=Global - Application - App_Performance_Test - feature-Jmeter-Test-Feature - JMeter\nbamboo_capability_system_agent_environment_iam_instance_profile=gd-mantl-agent\nbamboo_planRepository_1_revision=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_repository_name=Global - jmeter-scripts\nbamboo_domain=www-bose-com\nbamboo_repository_247496707_previous_revision_number=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_ci_user=gc8281256\nbamboo_buildFailed=false\nbamboo_capability_system_docker_executable=/usr/bin/docker\nbamboo_agentWorkingDirectory=/media/ephemeral0/build-dir\nbamboo_gdtempversion=17216\nbamboo_capability_system_git_executable=/usr/bin/git\nbamboo_repository_git_username=\nbamboo_planRepository_1_previousRevision=06bbe6dbc1ab56007bf4b44e270b72d477e7fee6\nbamboo_planRepository_branchDisplayName=feature/Jmeter-Test-Feature\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_mvn3_Maven_3_x=/opt/maven/current\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_awscli=/usr/local/bin/aws\nbamboo_plan_storageTag=plan-247365637\nbamboo_repository_git_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash-QA.gd.com:7999/project/jmeter-scripts.git\nbamboo_repository_247496707_git_username=\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_knife=/opt/chefdk/bin/knife\nbamboo_working_directory=/media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1\nbamboo_planRepository_1_repositoryUrl=ssh://git@stash-QA.gd.com:7999/project/jmeter-scripts.git\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_8=/opt/jdk-8\nbamboo_capability_system_jdk_JDK_1_9=/opt/jdk-9\nbamboo_capability_system_builder_command_chrome=/usr/bin/google-chrome\n
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25  _   _  ____  _  _
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 ( )_( )(  _ \( )/ )
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25  ) _ (  ) _ < )  ( 
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 (_) (_)(____/(_)\_) 
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 This build has been killed by the HBK (Hung Build Killer). Either Bamboo has detected the build has hung or it has been manually stopped.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 Attempting to generate stack trace and terminate spawned sub-processes of process id: 2282
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 Found related process: pid: 2659 ppid: 2282 pgid: 2174 %cpu: 0.0 %mem: 0.0 cmd: /bin/sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3-ScriptBuildTask-5020464262256623767.sh
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 Found related process: pid: 2660 ppid: 2659 pgid: 2174 %cpu: 0.0 %mem: 0.0 cmd: /bin/bash
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 getStackTraceAndKillRelatedProcesses for 2 processes
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 Executing kill -3 2660
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:25 Executing kill -3 2659
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Killing: 2660
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Executing kill 2660
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Killing: 2659
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Executing kill 2659
error 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Terminated
error 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3-ScriptBuildTask-5020464262256623767.sh: 2: cd: can't cd to /opt/apache-jmeter-3/bin/jmeter
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Failing task since return code of [/bin/sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/GDA-AP10-JOB1-3-ScriptBuildTask-5020464262256623767.sh] was 2 while expected 0
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Finished task 'Test script' with result: Failed
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'Docker Container Cleanup'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'Clover Results Collector'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'Sauce OnDemand Post Runner'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'npm Cache Cleanup'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running post build plugin 'Artifact Copier'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Publishing an artifact: jmeter_jtl
error 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Unable to publish artifact [jmeter_jtl]: the source directory /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1/output does not exist.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 The artifact hasn't been successfully published after 456.8 μs
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Finalising the build...
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Stopping timer.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Build GDA-AP10-JOB1-3 completed.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running on server: post build plugin 'NCover Results Collector'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running on server: post build plugin 'Build Hanging Detection Configuration'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running on server: post build plugin 'Clover Delta Calculator'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Running on server: post build plugin 'Maven Dependencies Postprocessor'
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 All post build plugins have finished
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Generating build results summary...
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Saving build results to disk...
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:30 Logging substituted variables...
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:31 Indexing build results...
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:31 Finished building GDA-AP10-JOB1-3.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35  _   _  ____  _  _
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35 ( )_( )(  _ \( )/ )
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35  ) _ (  ) _ < )  ( 
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35 (_) (_)(____/(_)\_) 
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35 This build has been killed by the HBK (Hung Build Killer). Either Bamboo has detected the build has hung or it has been manually stopped.
simple 14-Jan-2019 16:02:35 Has finished generating stack trace and terminating spawned sub-processes of process id: 2282
```

I am planning to automate performance testing through Bamboo. Currently, I am running performance tests using jmeter 3.1 installed on a Windows machine (AWS-EC2 instance).

I am following the below approach to automate my tests:

1. Create a repository in stash, upload the jmx file
2. Create a bamboo plan, with  a stage(jmeter)->task 1(Source Code Checkout configuration- configured the above repository) and task 2 (Script configuration).
3. In the second task, I choose `/bin/sh` or `cmd.exe` then I have written the code in the script body section:

   ```
   /bin/bash   
   cd ${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.JMeter 3} -n -t \
   jmeterscript.jmx -l ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/example.jtl  
   #runtime the value will be    
   #${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.JMeter 3}   
   # (which is interpolated to `/opt/apache-jmeter-3/bin/jmeter`)
   ```

When I run the above plan, it runs for more than 30 mins and fails.

Here's the error I receive (logs are in-line, above):

```
can't cd to /opt/apache-jmeter-3/bin/jmeter  
   Unable to publish artifact [jmeter_jtl]: the source directory 
   /media/ephemeral0/build-dir/GDA-AP10-JOB1/output does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

`cd ${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.JMeter 3} -n -t \jmeterscript.jmx -l ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/example.jtl`
By this command you are trying to change dir. But there is no such dir actually.

You have to run JMeter instead:
`${bamboo.capability.system.builder.command.JMeter 3} -n -t \jmeterscript.jmx -l ${bamboo.build.working.directory}/example.jtl`